# Mylyn loses tasks context on restart

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

When I restart Eclipse, my Mylyn tasks are stored, but their contexts are empty. 
I'm using a local repository, and would like to have the context of a task back when I reopen Eclipse.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.0 and Mylyn 3.0.4.

Comment: Thank you for your precisions about eclipse and Mylyn versions. I will check this in a few hours. In the meantime, hopefully, another SO contributor will have some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the bug you're seeing? [211168](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=211168)

Comment: Seems to be the case, because I can't reproduce the error I reported after upgrading to version '3.0.4.v20090122-1000-e3x'

Answer (score 0):

What Eclipse and Mylyn version are you using ?

The is a [**bug**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=232664) somewhat relative to this issue, supposedly fixed, but only in Mylyn 2.3 (in eclipse3.4)

---

Do not forget, according to the **[Mylyn FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/FAQ#Why_am_I_missing_elements_when_I_retrieve_someone_else.E2.80.99s_context.3F)**, that:

> To identify elements within a project, Mylyn relies on the name of the project being consistent across workspaces.
>   If the project name in the workspace that the context was created with is different than its name in your workspace, the task context will not show elements within that project ([bug 164058](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=164058)).
>   The other case where context can be lost is if the elements change names outside of the workspace ([bug 164243](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=164243)).

(not exactly your issue, but still something to check)

Comment: I'm afraid this is not my issue. I don't change the workspace in the process, just restart Eclipse.